# Yii, set radio button value fetch from database

Tags: yii, yii-components, cgridview, yii-chtml

In Yii, I listed my table which is fetch from database in grid view.

```
'value'=> 'CHtml::radioButton("set_default",false,array(
             "value"=>"$data->id",
             "set"=>"1",
             "disable"=>"disable",
              "uncheckValue"=>null  
            ))',
```

the above code I entered in normal radio button view, how do I fetch from database? Anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

[CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) lets you write any value inside row's column instead of normal database values. For modify column values, you need to add a function for `value` attribute. Inside of this function, you can access each data's attributes. In your case, You need to echo a radio button like this:

```
 //$data refres to each data row in the CGridView
'value' => function ($data, $row) {
        echo  
        CHtml::radioButton("set_default",false,array(
            "value"=>$data->id,
            "set"=>"1",
            "disable"=>"disable",
            "uncheckValue"=>null  
        )),                      
 },
```